# center a wxStaticText on a wxWindow with wxBoxSizer

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to center my wxStaticText on a wxWindow but it seems this not works. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/gbsizer.h>

using namespace std;

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
 wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL,wxID_ANY,wxT("fenetre"));
 wxWindow *win = new wxWindow(frame,wxID_ANY);
 win->SetWindowStyle(wxBORDER_RAISED);
 wxStaticText *text = new wxStaticText(win,wxID_STATIC,wxT("Mon texte"));
 wxBoxSizer *b = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
 wxGridBagSizer *box = new wxGridBagSizer();
 wxButton *button = new wxButton(frame,wxID_ANY,wxT("salut"));
 b->Add(text,0,wxALIGN_CENTRE);
 win->SetSizer(b);
 box->Add(win,wxGBPosition(0,0),wxDefaultSpan,wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER|wxGROW);
 box->Add(button,wxGBPosition(1,0),wxDefaultSpan,wxALL|wxGROW);
 box->AddGrowableCol(0);
 box->AddGrowableRow(0);
 box->AddGrowableRow(1);
 frame->SetSizer(box);
 frame->Show(true);
 return true; 
}

DECLARE_APP(MyApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

I don't know what is wrong but wxStaticText doesn't center itself on my wxWindow. Please, tell me What is missing.

My code with wxStaticText directly on the frame.

```
#include <wx/gbsizer.h>

using namespace std;

class MyApp: public wxApp
 {
     virtual bool OnInit();
 };

 bool MyApp::OnInit()
 {
   wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL,wxID_ANY,wxT("fenetre"));
   //wxFrame *win = new wxFrame(frame,wxID_ANY,wxT("hh"));
   wxStaticText *text = new       wxStaticText(frame,wxID_STATIC,wxT("Mon texte"),wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  text->SetWindowStyle(wxBORDER_RAISED);
  //wxBoxSizer *b = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
  wxGridBagSizer *box = new wxGridBagSizer();
  wxButton *button = new wxButton(frame,wxID_ANY,wxT("salut"));
  //b->Add(text,0,wxALIGN_CENTRE);
  //win->SetSizer(b);
  box->Add(text,wxGBPosition(0,0),wxDefaultSpan,wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER);
  box->Add(button,wxGBPosition(1,0),wxDefaultSpan,wxALL|wxGROW);
  box->AddGrowableCol(0);
  box->AddGrowableRow(0);
  box->AddGrowableRow(1);
  frame->SetSizer(box);
  frame->Show(true);
  return true;
 }

 DECLARE_APP(MyApp)
 IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

Comment: Do you want to center the text horizontally or vertically? I see that you pass `wxVERTICAL` when creating the `wxBoxSizer` but if you want to center horizontally, shouldn't it be `wxHORIZONTAL`?

Comment: You code sample is too complex!  Does the problem occur when you remove the  wxGridBagSizer *box code?

Comment: I want to code something like a RAISED area on which I can put a text to the center of this area so my wxWindow is my raised area and wxStaticText the text which has to center itself on my wxWindow. wxGridBagSizer it is just for a more complexe widget but I need it.          I have notice that, if I place the wxStaticText directly to the frame area after adding it to the first place on my wxGridBagSizer: wxPosition(0,0), the wxStatictText is perfectly in the frame's center but the cell in which it is, is not raised. But when I remove it and I put it in a wxWindow object nothing good happens.

Comment: I have add another code on my first code to show you, what happens when I place wxStaticText directly on my frame

Comment: DO NOT place controls directly on a frame i.e as a child of the frame.  It is best to create a wxPanel as a single child of the frame and place your controls as children of the panel.  Please, please, look at the sample applications and follow the way that things are done in them.

Comment: No, my controls are not directly on my frame, look at my second code. My controls are managed by wxGridBagSizer which in turn is set to my frame. I add my wxStaticText first to my wxGridBagSizer and after doing tha I set my wxGridBagSizer to my frame, this Sizer lays out my wxStaticText on my frame.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT place controls directly on a frame i.e as a child of the frame.

Don't do this:

```
wxStaticText *text = new       wxStaticText(frame,wxID_STATIC,wxT("Mon texte"),
```

It is best to create a wxPanel as a single child of the frame and place your controls as children of the panel.

Please, please, please, please look at the sample applications and follow the way that things are done in them.

If you use the sample application code as a starting point, then you will save a great deal of time, your own and everyone else's time.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't see anything which explain me the differents roles play by sizers and containers clearly. I assumed that, sizers was anothers containers so this why I'm doing wrongs things. So please could give me some documentation about sizers and container? I have the cross-platform... book but really, nothings is clearly defined in cainteners window

Comment: Container?  A container, in the usual jargon, is an object that contains other objects - like a vector or a list.  Do you mean a window?  A sizer is an invisible window.

Comment: Yes a "container windows" that is the term used in the cross-platform book. but Sizer is not a window isn't it?? container windows is some thing on which you can lay out your controls but in defining a position by hand and the controls's size by hand too. Sizer is used to automaticaly resize and set position for all controls.

Comment: wxPanel it is used to give to other wxWindow like wxframe which is not a wxDialog some proprieties of wxDialog which permit us to arrnage childreen control and others things in wxFrame. In plus, with all layout Sizers we could manage automaticaly set postion and size of all these controls. In some we shoudl first place a wxpanel on a wxFrame before doing anything else